# PHP Prevent Session Hacking

Tags: php, session

I'm currently working on a PHP browser based game. I have most of the script done but I'm worried that someone could easily 'hack' the session.

When a user log in and the password is correct, `$_SESSION['logged']` will become '1'. The user will be redirected to profile.php .

If `$_SESSION['logged']` is equal to '1', the profile will be displayed. However, if `$_SESSION['logged']` doesn't exist, the user will be redirected back to index.php.

I'm afraid that the user will be able to hack `$_SESSION['logged']`.

Also, there is `$_SESSION['username']`. Most of the time I use `$_SESSION['username']` to fetch information from database. If `$_SESSION['username']` were changed/hacked, the 'hacker' will than be able to 'become' another 'person'.

I heard about session_regenerate_id and session_id() . However, I'm not sure where to place them.

Thanks,

Comment: The player, or *client*, cannot change the values from `$_SESSION`.

Comment: You shouldn't store `$_SESSION['logged']`; you can use token-based authentication instead.

Comment: @Raptor I use this way to understand if a user is admin or no, what is other and best way?

Comment: @scrowler Aren't sessions established and maintained through cookies in most scenarios (absent sending the session id through every POST/GET)?  Sessions can be hacked by a man in the middle, but for most people's needs, they're "secure enough".

Comment: you should store the "admin or not" settings in DB.

Answer (score 3):

**session_regenerate_id** *Update* the current session id with a newly generated one.This might be useful if, for example, you want to refresh the session ID every **10 minutes** or after changing the state of authenticity of a user associated with a session.

and you should know about

- [Session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack)
- [Session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation)

and if you want to know more take a look at [PHP security](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)